# Cat-like people who can fly to space on crosses. Telekinetic powers. Cold world. Construct mirrors in space to warm planet. Probably 70's or 80's

Tags: story-identification, aliens, space, space-exploration

Anyone know this book?

I'm looking for a trilogy about a female who grows up in the country and is rescued after some kind of raid and brought to the main city. Over the trilogy, she is trained in telekinetic (and other?) powers that are part of training to go into space. Only women can go into space. It's a matriarchal society and low technology. Based on their mind powers instead. They fly into space on crosses of special wood.

She's also been set up to compete with the top female from another group or clan.

Their planet is getting colder and in the last book (I think) they construct giant mirrors to reflect sun to warm their world. Later, they meet a spacefaring species that is more like us. After some attempts at peace, a war breaks out in which she wrecks havoc. Finally, she commits suicide to allow peace, if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 6):

Sounds like the [Darkwar Saga](http://greenmanreview.com/books/glen-cook-darkwars-doomstalker-warlock-ceremony-2/) by [Glen Cook](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glen_Cook). I asked a [similar question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2103/what-fantasy-book-features-a-feline-race-and-a-female-lead-character-in-a-world) with similar details a while back, and it sounds like we are talking about the exact same books.

From LAK's comment:

> The characters are described using wolf-like terms (pup, pack). The solar system is passing through a dust causing the planet to cool. Main character is a primitive adopted by one of the clans because of her extreme 'witch' powers. She's set up as a rival to another witch from another clan. They can fly (including through space) on cross-like ships using their powers. They eventually encounter humans in space. The main character tries to force her people to save themselves with the orbital mirrors but ends up despairing.

Comment: I don't soppose you could provide more details. The most I can tell from your link, and a Wikipedia search, is that the Darkwar books feature a matriarchal society.

Comment: Agreed, Darkwar Trilogy by Glen Cook.  The characters are  described using wolf-like terms (pup, pack).  The solar system is passing through a dust causing the planet to cool.  Main character is a primitive adopted by one of the clans because of her extreme 'witch' powers.  She's set up as a rival to another witch from another clan.  They can fly (including through space) on cross-like ships using their powers.  They eventually encounter humans in space.  The main character tries to force her people to save themselves with the orbital mirrors but ends up despairing.